# Creating a method with parameter that accepts NSString or int

Tags: objective-c

Trying to create a method with only one parameter that may accept NSString or int.

Here's what I did so far:

```
-(NSString*)LocalizeNumber:(void*)TheNumber{
    BOOL IsVarInt = false;
    NSString * Num = "";
    if(IsVarInt){
        Num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(int)TheNumber];
    }else{
        Num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(__bridge NSString*)TheNumber];
    }
    //rest of code...
}
```

And this is how I call this method:

if passing int:

```
[self LocalizeNumber:(void*)150];
```

if passing NSString:

```
[self LocalizeNumber:@"150"];
```

The problem is that I still don't know how to know if the parameter "TheNumber" is NSString or int.

Thank you.

Comment: The first way of passing an `int` won't work. Why can't you have two separate methods, one that takes a string, the other an integer?

Comment: @SevenBits Thanks for the tip, I will end doing it if there's no way to use one parameter. by the way, passing int is working, I've tested it.

Comment: It may work in that circumstance (haven't tested it) but in many circumstances it will silently fail. This should be done the correct way, either by using the method I suggested or by using a `va_list`.

Comment: This seems like a strange way to do it--why ever pass a string to LocalizeNumber? Do you now know at the call site if you have a string or a number? Maybe this isn't all your code? (BTW it's standard to name it "localizeNumber" with a lowercase letter)

Comment: You could write it in Swift--it has method overloading on argument type I believe.

Comment: @nielsbot at some point, I have to pass strings to LocalizeNumber because numbers in Arabic will remain english numbers even if the whole device is localized to arabic, so I have to use some ascii code to force the numbers to be shown as arabic numbers. And I always use uppercase at first letter :)

Comment: can't you use *NSNumberFormatter*?

Comment: tried it, but only working in Android when converting the app using Apportable, also I will use this method too much so it has to be lite. I will use LocalizeNumber only in showing sentences, but in calculation i will use int only.

Comment: Then use NSNumberFormatter on iOS and whatever else on Android. Use NSNumberFormatter within your *-localizeNumber* method and cache the formatter for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I suggest you rethink your approach, your goal can be achieved as follows:

```
- (NSString *)localizeNumber:(id)number {
    NSString *num = nil;

    if ([number isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        num = [number stringValue];
    } else if ([number isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        num = number;
    } else {
        // oops - bad value
    }

    // rest of code using num
}
```

Then you can call the method as follows:

```
NSString *someString = @"Hello";
NSString *result = [self localizeNumber:someString];
```

or:

```
int someInt = 42;
NSString *result = [self localizeNumber:@(someInt)];
```

Comment: Thanks for posting how to call the method.

Comment: FYI, this only works because the `int` is being converted into an `NSNumber` object by the compiler using the `@` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell between an object type and a plain primitive. However, you can easily tell between two object types if you pass an `int` passed in `NSNumber` wrapper, like this:

```
-(NSString*)LocalizeNumber:(id)TheNumber {
    NSString *Num = @"";
    if ([TheNumber isKindOfClass:[NSSTRING class]]) {
        Num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", TheNumber];
    } else if ([TheNumber isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        Num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[TheNumber intValue]];
    }
    //rest of code...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use categories to add *-stringValue* to *NSString*:

```
@implementation NSString (LocalizedNumber)
-(NSString*)stringValue
{
    return self ;
}
@end
```

Then you can call:

```
NSString * localizedNumber = [<number or string object> stringValue]
```

There is no safe way to tell an *int* from an *NSString* reference.

Comment: This doesn't help the OP at all. You return another string. How does that help the OP get an integer?

Comment: His original code returns a string. I don't understand what you are getting at. He wanted code that works for strings or numbers--this does. Just call *-stringValue* on whatever you have. This category makes it work for *NSString* and it already works for *NSNumber*.

Comment: You can also use a custom method and add it to both NSNumber and NSString

Comment: Okay, I understand now. While this does do what the OP wants, it is not clear that this works due to features of Objective-C. Also, it should be made clear that this will only work if the `int` is wrapped in an `NSNumber`.